# How to call synchronised block in microservices?

Tags: microservices

I am writing Spring boot microservices to operation on user's bank account balance. How to achieve this so that if the user is doing operation from website, mobile and ATM, there should be consistency in it. 
When multiple instance of microservice will run independently they can't be synchronous and my synchronous block will no longer be useful.

Comment: You can use db transactions

Comment: I assume there would be shared relational databases and all your microservices instances will be using that. Relational database makes sure that transaction is ACID